# Java Static Classes lifetime

Tags: java, jsp

How is a Java static class garbage collected?

I have a static class, which contains a static object.  If I set the object to null then it is garbage collected.  I don't understand the lifecycle of a static class.  Is it garbage collected when the program closes?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "static classes."  All top-level classes behave like static classes, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this way:

Every object has a reference to its class.

Every class has a reference to its class loader.

Every class loader has a reference to *every class it has ever loaded*.

It is possible that this whole ball of mess becomes garbage. This is the basis for app unloading/reloading (in a servlet container). However if there's even one object still referenced, the class loader and all its classes cannot be unloaded, therefore it is not an easy task to achieve app unloading.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't suppose you know if this is the same in .NET languages.  I come from a Java background but I am programming in .NET languages these days.

Comment: why not post a .net question.

Answer (score 4):

**Static objects are tied with the class definition and not with the class instance.**

They come into effect **as soon as your class is loaded** through the ClassLoader and destroyed only when class is unloaded.

Comment: Thanks, when is the class unloaded?

Comment: @w0051977: When your class is out of e.g. context e.g. if you were running the program in stand alone mode and program is terminated or if you had a web application with static classes deployed and you un-deploy the application. In summary, its unloaded when the loading context itself is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, if it is a web application then I assume that the "loading context" is the windows process?

Comment: @w0051977: no. Each deployed webapp has its own classloader, and the classloader and all its classes are GCed when the app is undeployed, even if the Java process isn't terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Static classes are always accessible and therefore never garbage collected.

Now, if your static class has as it's field and instance of a non-static class and that gets set to null, than that memory will be freed up because that object is no longer referenced.

for instance

```
public static StaticClass
{
    public static InstanceClass myInstanceClass;
}
```

if you set `myInstanceClass` to null, then it will be garbage collected.

Comment: I understand how and when myInstanceClass is garbage collected.  I don't understand when StaticClass is garbage collected.  Surely it must be unloaded from memory?

Comment: @w0051977 when you close the program it will be

Comment: @w0051977 try setting your static class to null

Comment: @SamIam: you can't set a class to null. You're talking nonsense.

Comment: @JBNizet EXACTLY, that's the point that I was trying to make.  It doesn't even make sense to set your static class to null, therefore, it doesn't make sense to garbage collect it until your program has terminated

Answer (score 1):

**-** `static` class can **only be at class level not at package level**, we can say `static inner classes` or `Top level classes`.

**-** A `static` class is then loaded by the class loader.

**-** Now the `static` class will be into the memory till the **loader** that has loaded it is still running or unless its not unloaded by the loader.